# nginx using remote_addr to get ipv6

Tags: nginx, ipv6

Since I don't have an IPv6 address to work with.

If I had a server block like this:

```
server{
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    root /some/root;
    server_name some.name;
    index some_index.html;
    location / {
        return "$remote_addr";
    }
}
```

Would this return the ipv6 address?
I am assuming yes since its forcing ipv6only.

Comment: Almost all modern servers have at least link-local IPv6 address. Check `ping6 ::1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

Nginx' return directive expects a HTTP status code as an argument.

But you can use the echo module for this purpose:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name some.name;
    location / {
        echo "$remote_addr";
    }
}
```